# iOS: NSDefault Will Not Save / Load When App Terminates

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Dear Experts and Friends,

Hi, I have been trying to get this down for the whole day, but nothing I have tried seems to work. Basically I would like to save an array of strings (max: 20, nothing heavy weight) using NSDefault. It saves, it loads ok, but not when I killed the App on real device by pressing the Minus Button. I tested it on an iPhone 4gs (iOS 6).

I have tried  
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 

in both 

    applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application 

and 

    applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`


But it didn't work.

Note: from NSLog, I am getting the values back fine from NSDefault as long as I don't kill the application in background on real device.

Does anyone know why? Many thanks in advance. Please cite with samples.

========================= EDIT (ADDING CODE):

I am adding in some code, in hopes that it will be clearer and that someone can really help me out here.

Thanks in advance.
some action, then

```
self.count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.count intValue] + 1];
count is a NSNumber 
 NSData *count = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.count];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:count forKey:@"count"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
arrayForSavedKey is a NSMutableArray
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSData *array = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.arrayForSavedKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"arrayForSavedKeys"];
```

In Both:
 
    applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

```
applicationWillEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

I have tried added the following line
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
To retrieve the data, I have the Delegate to call a method in class A
by calling:
     loadSavedData 
and unarchiving like so:

```
NSData *savedKeys = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"arrayForSavedKeys"];<br>
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedKeys]];<br>
self.arrayForSavedKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array];<br>
```

(There are only a few NSStrings in it)

In which I NSLOG the output and everything is fine SO LONG AS I do not kill the app by the Minus sign.
(But with a real device I cannot see anything from NSLog, of course, because once I killed the App, App will stop running as well in xCode)

I have spent all day today and I am running the end of my wits. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `applicationWillTerminate:` is only called for a few very special cases so don't bother using that.

Using `applicationWillEnterForeground:` to save your defaults is way too late.

The proper place to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` is in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method. This way, if you app is killed in the background, the defaults have already been saved.

Comment: Using the debugger (or an `NSLog` statement), have you verified the call to `synchronize` is being reached when your app enters the background?